# apr fails to configure when building subversion

Tags: svn, debian, libxml2, apr

I am trying to build subversion 1.7.4 on my ReadyNas Duo, it's a Sparc box running Debian with a couple of disks in it I use as my NAS.

When i do a ./configure --prefix /c/local/packages from my subversion-1.7.4 directory
I get
configure: error: No XML parser found!  Please specify --with-expat or --with-libxml2

apr is failing to configure, says it can find libxml2 -- which is there /usr/lib/limxml2.so, I've also done an apt-get install libxml2-dev

The thing is so dog slow it takes ages to fail, I would use a binary dist but the eclipse plug in didn't want to play with it because it was too old...

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick was to cd into the apr directory in the subversion source directory and do a ./configure --with-libxml2=/usr/lib before returning to the subversion source directory and running ./configure from there again.

Not the last problem encountered for anyone wishing to build the latest subversion on a ReadyNAS Duo

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to have finished building Subversion 1.7.4 on Redhat REL-5.3. I had to update **everything**. The system came with Subversion 1.3.x. Why our company can't use anything newer than a 5.3 is a mystery to me.

If you want to use Apache httpd as your server, you might have to rebuild Apache, so you can build the required `mod_dav_svn.o` Apache module. See if this module is already located inside your Apache module directories. (On most Linux systems, it's a link from `/etc/httpd/modules`.)

Be very careful about parsing through the output of your configure script. For example, out of hundreds of line, I found a reference that `neon` wasn't found. No `neon`, no http access from Subversion.

Here's a list of modules I downloaded:

- apr
- apr-util
- autoconf-2.68 (I think this was for Apache)
- neon-0.29.6
- prce-8.20 (for Apache for `mod_perl.o` not really necessary)
- sqlite-amalgamoation-3071000 (had to replace sqlite3.c in SVN source)
- Apache's httd-2.4.1

And to build Subversion, I had to download a [patch](http://www.thorko.de/assets/public/subversion.patch) in order to build `mod_dav_svn`.

If I remember, I had to set `-with-apr` and `--with-aprutil` pointing to the `apr-1-util` and `apu-1-util` files. Everything installed in `/usr/local` without me having to specify a directory. Didn't run into an expat issue. However, I have libexpat.so.0.5.0 installed on my system under the `/lib` directory with a link from `/usr/lib`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks David, I have the job done now, been through the same pain, should really do a cheat sheet for any other poor soul that is sad enough to want subversion on their NAS.